# ® gets converted to Â® in Python while parsing XML

Tags: python, xml, rss, non-ascii-characters

My RSS feed ontains:

```
<title><![ CDATA[HBO Wins 19 Emmy® Awards, The Most of Any Network This Year]]></title>
```

Now I am parsing RSS and then assigning the title to title as below:

```
 for item in XML.ElementFromURL(feed).xpath('//item',namespaces=NEWS_NS):
        title = item.find('title').text
        Log("Title :"+title)
```

and when I am checking the out put or the log file then I see the title as below:

> HBO Wins 19 EmmyÂ® Awards, The Most of Any Network This Year.

® gets converted to Â® . Any I tried using HTML parser but no use.

Comment: Define what ® means. What encoding is the feed in? What encoding are you printing to? Why are you not using the marvellous http://www.feedparser.org/? Also notice that in your `Log()` call you're casting the title to a `str` even if the object was a proper `unicode` instance.

Comment: @patrys, The feed , encoding="iso-8859-1" . is feedparser.org is external library? In that case I can not use this. And  Can you please clarify " What encoding are you printing to?"

Comment: It seems you get a proper utf-8 representation of the “®” character but print it to a `latin1` (`iso-8859-1`) output. I suspect the problem is not in the way you decode the feed but rather in the way you `Log()` the results or view the logged results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following and worked:

```
title = item.find('title').text
title = title.encode('iso-8859-1')
```

When I am getting the string converted to UTF-8(® to Â® ) and I am converting it back to iso-8859-1(Â®  to ® ) and getting the correct output

Comment: Chances are there are now *two* bugs in your application.  One is the cause of your original problem.  The other is this "fix".

Answer (score 1):

You state that the encoding of the feed is ISO-8859-1.

In that case, if the bytes that you say should be interpreted as `®` are in fact `C2 AE`, then the text **really, truly** is `EmmyÂ® Awards`, and everything is working as it should.  If the sender intended different text, they would have sent different data or set the encoding differently.

If the encoding of the feed were UTF-8, and the bytes sent over the wire were still `C2 AE`, then the text would be `Emmy® Awards`.

If the encoding of the feed were ISO-8859-1, and the bytes sent over the wire were simply `AE`, with no `C2`, then the text would be `Emmy® Awards`.

To be sure what the bytes are, use the `od -x` command in Unix or the `d` command in `debug.exe` for Windows.  Don't trust Notepad in situations like this.  It lies.

Answer (score 0):

You've received some text encoded using UTF-8, but at some point those bytes are being incorrectly interpreted as ISO-8859-1 or another encoding instead.

Without more context, it's difficult to tell exactly where the mistake is taking place. You should first check the encoding being used to read your log file.

Comment: The encoding being used to read the Log is 'UTF-8' .Any suggestion to get this working!!!!